# How to find the class inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my HTML format.

```
<div id="myid">

    <div class="first-class">

    </div>
    <div class="second-class">

    </div>
    <div class="third-class">

    </div>

</div>
```

What I want to achieve is find the **third-class** using the **myid**. How to achieve that? Thank you sir!

Comment: All people here are not "sir", sir.

Comment: Are you trying to find the third element, regardless of its class name? Or will it always have the `third-class` class?

Comment: @cederlof well said sir

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find` method.

```
$('#myid').find('.third-class')
```

**OR**

```
$('#myid .third-class')
```

**OR**

```
$('#myid').children('.third-class')
```

**OR**

```
$('.third-class', '#myid')
```

Comment: or $('.third-class', '#myid')

Comment: @TravisJ Missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure JavaScript something like

```
var thirdElem = document.getElementById('myid').getElementsByClassName("third-class")[0];
```

First we search the particular element by it's id (**'myid'**) and we find the particular element by class (**'third-class'**) inside the element (**'myid'**).

**OR**

You can use **querySelecotr**, something like,

`var thirdElem = document.querySelector('#myid .third-class');`

In this case **querySelector** fetches the first element with class **.third-class** from  **div(#myid)**.

Comment: thank you bro!!! it's worked for me.can you kindly explain the purpose of [0] in getElementsByClassName

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns the array of node element, by doing `[0]` 
 we are getting the first element from that array. However in above case, there would be the single element of array.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if trying to find the third element regardless of class name, something like this:

```
$('#myid').children().eq(2)
```

(It's '2' since the index is zero-based), as example:

```
var className = $('#myid').children().eq(2).attr('class');
// className would be 'third-class'
```